# Como usar numero gerado pelo FOR no nome de uma variável?

Tags: javascript

Como usar numero gerado pelo FOR no nome de uma variável ?

Exemplo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
var teste[i] = "teste é " +[i];
}
```

Exemplo 2:

```
for (var b = 0; b < 5; b++) { 
var teste[b] = "teste";
}
```

**OU**

Tenho que criar um grupo de variáveis numeradas, exemplo:

```
var teste1
var teste2
var teste3...
```

Qual a melhor forma sem ser uma por uma ?

Comment: Cria um array. Do tipo: teste[i]... Não precisa salvar cada um como uma variável.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Embora seja [possível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21447/), evite criar variáveis com nomes dinâmicos!

Nesses seus exemplos, você pode muito bem usar arrays, onde cada valor pode ser obtido pelo índice.

Quando você diz `[i]`, está criando uma array com o `i` dentro. Se entendi bem a pergunta, você quer simplesmente o valor `i`:

```
var teste = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    teste[i] = "teste é " + i;
}
```

Repare que eu também alterei sua declaração `var teste[i]`, que é um erro de sintaxe. Declare a array fora do loop, e dentro somente atribua cada posição. Outra alternativa é usar `push`:

```
var teste = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    teste.push("teste é " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A [resposta do bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21443/215) é a mais recomendada, mas caso você precise **incluir** o índice numérico no nome da variável por algum motivo, você pode usar um objeto qualquer (incluindo o objeto global `window`) e atribuir-lhe novas propriedades dinamicamente:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    window["teste" + i] = "teste é " + i;
}
alert(teste3); // "teste é 3"

var testes = {};
for (var b = 0; b < 5; b++) { 
    testes["teste" + b] = "teste";
}
alert(testes.teste3); // "teste"
```

(no caso de atribuir a `window`, ela vira uma global; no outro caso, é preciso prefixar com o objeto criado; não existem meios de se criar uma variável local dessa forma)

Note que isso **não é uma boa prática**, entre outras coisas porque você não consegue iterar sobre suas variáveis criadas de forma fácil (como seria se você usasse um array). Apenas estou respondendo literalmente ao que foi perguntado.

Comment: Até existe como criar uma variável local (com `eval`), mas ainda bem que você não explicou :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Ei, é verdade! Será que atualizo minha resposta? :P (falando sério, estou na dúvida se mantenho essa resposta ou excluo - tecnicamente está correta, mas é 110% inútil... Não consigo pensar em um único caso de uso pra ela, e olha que eu já abusei bastante de tudo quanto é linguagem em tarefas de meta-programação.) A propósito, interessante que alguém possa criar variáveis locais dinamicamente, mas não exista um meio de **listar** todas as variáveis locais...

Comment: A minha resposta ficou meio estranha depois que a pergunta foi editada, porque eu estava respondendo outra coisa... A sua responde o que foi perguntado. Pelo menos uma complementa a outra.

Comment: Sobre listar as variáveis locais, poderia muito bem haver algo "mágico" como `arguments` com a lista de propriedades (incluindo as "herdadas" via closures), só que ninguém nunca implementou. Acredito que implementar *não* viola a especificação. Seria interessante, mas imagina como iriam abusar disso. Seria o novo `eval`.